# Is it compulsory to partition data in training and testing for time series modelling?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, partitioning

Is it compulsory to partition data in training and testing for time series modelling ?

The reason for asking this question:
Lets say training data= first 80% observation of actual time series data(not using random sampling because if we use it, we won't be able to capture trend)

and testing data = last 20% data.
If we build model on training data (we are leaving most recent observations to train the model), then we won't be able to capture recent effect in model. 
So it may lead to underfit situation, which we don't want.

Comment: @SmallChess some articles are suggesting to go for sequence partition rather than random.

Comment: @SmallChess Did you perhaps miss the part about the fact that this is a time series task? In that case, training sets are typically chosen as ranges of data (in time order), and similarly for testing sets, which should occur afterwards. Otherwise 1) the randomly sampled training data probably does not follow the same process as the real data *at all* (even if kept in order) and 2) the tested task does not resemble the actual task we are trying to accomplish (using data up to now, forecast data in the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to Rob Hyndman's blog, in particular [this post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/) and its linked academic paper, wherein it is explained that in an auto-regressive/machine learning setting normal k-fold cross validation is OK. This avoids the problem of data partitioning.

Comment: The linked paper says: "When purely (non-linear, nonparametric)
autoregressive methods are applied to forecasting problems, as is often the case
(e.g., when using Machine Learning methods), the aforementioned problems of CV are largely
irrelevant, and CV can and should be used without modification, as in the independent case." Are RNNs and LSTMs purely auto-regressive methods? i.e. are they included in what the authors call  "Machine Learning methods"?

Comment: @arun, I would say RNN and LSTM are auto-regressive in that for any target only inputs prior to the target, for a given look back length, are used. However, care must be taken to ensure that no data appears in both the training and test folds of the cross validation procedure, which will mean that some data before and after the test fold data must be embargoed from the training fold data.

Comment: Thx. If interested, can you pls take a look at a separate qn I posted? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359157/normalization-and-train-dev-test-split-for-multi-dimensional-time-series